How to eliminate shift/reduce conflict in bison grammar?
I am trying to write a parser for HTTP and am coming across a shift/reduce conflict when including optional whitespace at the end of my header field. Does anyone have any tips on how to get around this?
I have written my grammar as follows and am getting a shift/reduce conflict on the second OWS token in line 14.
%{
  #define YYDEBUG 1
  int yylex(void);
  void yyerror(char *s);
%}
%token X00
%%

/* HTTP message definition */
HTTPMessage : startLine optHeaderField CRLF messageBody ;

/* Message is any repition of characters */
messageBody : /* empty */ | messageBody OCTET ;

/* Header field is optional and contains a field name followed by a colon, optional white space and followed by a field value */
optHeaderField : /* empty */ | optHeaderField headerField ;

headerField : fieldName ':' OWS fieldValue OWS CRLF ;

fieldValue : /* empty */ | fieldValue fieldValueSS ;

fieldValueSS : fieldContent | obsFold ; 

fieldContent : fieldVChar optFieldContent ;

optFieldContent : /* empty */ | RWS fieldVChar ;

fieldVChar : obsText | VCHAR ;

/* Even though this line fold is obsolete still account for it for consistency with the RFC */
obsFold : CRLF RWS ;

fieldName : token ;

token : tChar | token tChar ;

tChar : '!' | '#' | '$' | '%' | '&' | '\x27' | '*' | '+' | '-' | '.' | '^' | '_' | '`' | '|' | '~' | DIGIT | ALPHA ;

/* HTTP messages may either be requests or status messages */
startLine : statusLine CRLF | requestLine CRLF ;

/* A status message is a status message, followed by a status code, followed by a reason phrase */
statusLine : HTTPVersion SP statusCode SP reasonPhrase ;

statusCode : '1' DIGIT DIGIT | '2' DIGIT DIGIT | '3' DIGIT DIGIT | '4' DIGIT DIGIT | '5' DIGIT DIGIT ;

reasonPhrase : reasonPhraseSS | reasonPhrase reasonPhraseSS ;

reasonPhraseSS : HTAB | SP | VCHAR | obsText ;

obsText :     r__1 ;

/* A request message is a method, followed by a target (URI), followed by an HTTP version */
requestLine : method SP requestTarget SP HTTPVersion ;

requestTarget : originForm | absoluteForm | asteriskFrom ;

originForm : absolutePath queries ;

absoluteForm : absoluteURI ;

asteriskFrom : '*' ;

absolutePath : '/' segment | absolutePath '/' segment ;

absoluteURI : scheme ':' relativePart queries ;

relativePart : doubleSlashes hierPart ;

doubleSlashes: /* empty */ | '/' '/' ;

scheme: ALPHA schemes ;

schemes: /* empty */ | schemes schemess ;

schemess: ALPHA | DIGIT | '+' | '-' | '.' ;

hierPart: authority path ;

authority: host ports ;

host: unreserved | host unreserved ;

ports: /* empty */ | ':' port ;

port: DIGIT | port DIGIT ;

path: /* empty */ | path '/' segment ;

segment: /* empty */ | segment pchar ;

queries: /* empty */ | '?' query ;

query: /* empty */ | query queriess ;

queriess: pchar | '/' | '?' ;

pchar: unreserved | pct_encoded | sub_delims | ':' | '@' ;

pct_encoded: '%' HEXDIG HEXDIG ;

unreserved: ALPHA | DIGIT | '-' | '.' | '_' | '~' ;

sub_delims: '!' | '$' |     r__2 | ';' | '=' ;

/* HTTP version is the string HTTP followed by major-minor digit scheme */
HTTPVersion : s__0 '/' DIGIT '.' DIGIT ;

/* Tokens */
ALPHA : LOALPHA | UPALPHA ;

LOALPHA :     r__3 ;

UPALPHA :     r__4 ;

DIGIT :     r__5 ;

HEXDIG : DIGIT |     r__6 ;

SP : '\x20' ;

HTAB : '\x09' ;

WS : SP | HTAB ;

OWS : /* empty */ | OWS WS ;

RWS : WS | RWS WS ;

VCHAR :     r__7 ;

LF : '\x0a' ;

CR : '\x0d' ;

CRLF : CR LF ;

OCTET :     r__0 ;

method : s__1 | s__2 | s__3 | s__4 | s__5 | s__6 | s__7 | s__8 ;
/* Range Expansions */
r__0 : 
  X00 | '\x01' | '\x02' | '\x03' | '\x04' | '\x05' | '\x06' | '\x07' | 
  '\x08' | '\x09' | '\x0a' | '\x0b' | '\x0c' | '\x0d' | '\x0e' | '\x0f' | 
  '\x10' | '\x11' | '\x12' | '\x13' | '\x14' | '\x15' | '\x16' | '\x17' | 
  '\x18' | '\x19' | '\x1a' | '\x1b' | '\x1c' | '\x1d' | '\x1e' | '\x1f' | 
  '\x20' | '\x21' | '\x22' | '\x23' | '\x24' | '\x25' | '\x26' | '\x27' | 
  '\x28' | '\x29' | '\x2a' | '\x2b' | '\x2c' | '\x2d' | '\x2e' | '\x2f' | 
  '\x30' | '\x31' | '\x32' | '\x33' | '\x34' | '\x35' | '\x36' | '\x37' | 
  '\x38' | '\x39' | '\x3a' | '\x3b' | '\x3c' | '\x3d' | '\x3e' | '\x3f' | 
  '\x40' | '\x41' | '\x42' | '\x43' | '\x44' | '\x45' | '\x46' | '\x47' | 
  '\x48' | '\x49' | '\x4a' | '\x4b' | '\x4c' | '\x4d' | '\x4e' | '\x4f' | 
  '\x50' | '\x51' | '\x52' | '\x53' | '\x54' | '\x55' | '\x56' | '\x57' | 
  '\x58' | '\x59' | '\x5a' | '\x5b' | '\x5c' | '\x5d' | '\x5e' | '\x5f' | 
  '\x60' | '\x61' | '\x62' | '\x63' | '\x64' | '\x65' | '\x66' | '\x67' | 
  '\x68' | '\x69' | '\x6a' | '\x6b' | '\x6c' | '\x6d' | '\x6e' | '\x6f' | 
  '\x70' | '\x71' | '\x72' | '\x73' | '\x74' | '\x75' | '\x76' | '\x77' | 
  '\x78' | '\x79' | '\x7a' | '\x7b' | '\x7c' | '\x7d' | '\x7e' | '\x7f' | 
  '\x80' | '\x81' | '\x82' | '\x83' | '\x84' | '\x85' | '\x86' | '\x87' | 
  '\x88' | '\x89' | '\x8a' | '\x8b' | '\x8c' | '\x8d' | '\x8e' | '\x8f' | 
  '\x90' | '\x91' | '\x92' | '\x93' | '\x94' | '\x95' | '\x96' | '\x97' | 
  '\x98' | '\x99' | '\x9a' | '\x9b' | '\x9c' | '\x9d' | '\x9e' | '\x9f' | 
  '\xa0' | '\xa1' | '\xa2' | '\xa3' | '\xa4' | '\xa5' | '\xa6' | '\xa7' | 
  '\xa8' | '\xa9' | '\xaa' | '\xab' | '\xac' | '\xad' | '\xae' | '\xaf' | 
  '\xb0' | '\xb1' | '\xb2' | '\xb3' | '\xb4' | '\xb5' | '\xb6' | '\xb7' | 
  '\xb8' | '\xb9' | '\xba' | '\xbb' | '\xbc' | '\xbd' | '\xbe' | '\xbf' | 
  '\xc0' | '\xc1' | '\xc2' | '\xc3' | '\xc4' | '\xc5' | '\xc6' | '\xc7' | 
  '\xc8' | '\xc9' | '\xca' | '\xcb' | '\xcc' | '\xcd' | '\xce' | '\xcf' | 
  '\xd0' | '\xd1' | '\xd2' | '\xd3' | '\xd4' | '\xd5' | '\xd6' | '\xd7' | 
  '\xd8' | '\xd9' | '\xda' | '\xdb' | '\xdc' | '\xdd' | '\xde' | '\xdf' | 
  '\xe0' | '\xe1' | '\xe2' | '\xe3' | '\xe4' | '\xe5' | '\xe6' | '\xe7' | 
  '\xe8' | '\xe9' | '\xea' | '\xeb' | '\xec' | '\xed' | '\xee' | '\xef' | 
  '\xf0' | '\xf1' | '\xf2' | '\xf3' | '\xf4' | '\xf5' | '\xf6' | '\xf7' | 
  '\xf8' | '\xf9' | '\xfa' | '\xfb' | '\xfc' | '\xfd' | '\xfe' | '\xff' ;
r__1 : 
  '\x80' | '\x81' | '\x82' | '\x83' | '\x84' | '\x85' | '\x86' | '\x87' | 
  '\x88' | '\x89' | '\x8a' | '\x8b' | '\x8c' | '\x8d' | '\x8e' | '\x8f' | 
  '\x90' | '\x91' | '\x92' | '\x93' | '\x94' | '\x95' | '\x96' | '\x97' | 
  '\x98' | '\x99' | '\x9a' | '\x9b' | '\x9c' | '\x9d' | '\x9e' | '\x9f' | 
  '\xa0' | '\xa1' | '\xa2' | '\xa3' | '\xa4' | '\xa5' | '\xa6' | '\xa7' | 
  '\xa8' | '\xa9' | '\xaa' | '\xab' | '\xac' | '\xad' | '\xae' | '\xaf' | 
  '\xb0' | '\xb1' | '\xb2' | '\xb3' | '\xb4' | '\xb5' | '\xb6' | '\xb7' | 
  '\xb8' | '\xb9' | '\xba' | '\xbb' | '\xbc' | '\xbd' | '\xbe' | '\xbf' | 
  '\xc0' | '\xc1' | '\xc2' | '\xc3' | '\xc4' | '\xc5' | '\xc6' | '\xc7' | 
  '\xc8' | '\xc9' | '\xca' | '\xcb' | '\xcc' | '\xcd' | '\xce' | '\xcf' | 
  '\xd0' | '\xd1' | '\xd2' | '\xd3' | '\xd4' | '\xd5' | '\xd6' | '\xd7' | 
  '\xd8' | '\xd9' | '\xda' | '\xdb' | '\xdc' | '\xdd' | '\xde' | '\xdf' | 
  '\xe0' | '\xe1' | '\xe2' | '\xe3' | '\xe4' | '\xe5' | '\xe6' | '\xe7' | 
  '\xe8' | '\xe9' | '\xea' | '\xeb' | '\xec' | '\xed' | '\xee' | '\xef' | 
  '\xf0' | '\xf1' | '\xf2' | '\xf3' | '\xf4' | '\xf5' | '\xf6' | '\xf7' | 
  '\xf8' | '\xf9' | '\xfa' | '\xfb' | '\xfc' | '\xfd' | '\xfe' | '\xff' ;
r__2 : 
  '\x26' | '\x27' | '\x28' | '\x29' | '\x2a' | '\x2b' | '\x2c' ;
r__3 : 
  '\x61' | '\x62' | '\x63' | '\x64' | '\x65' | '\x66' | '\x67' | '\x68' | 
  '\x69' | '\x6a' | '\x6b' | '\x6c' | '\x6d' | '\x6e' | '\x6f' | '\x70' | 
  '\x71' | '\x72' | '\x73' | '\x74' | '\x75' | '\x76' | '\x77' | '\x78' | 
  '\x79' | '\x7a' ;
r__4 : 
  '\x41' | '\x42' | '\x43' | '\x44' | '\x45' | '\x46' | '\x47' | '\x48' | 
  '\x49' | '\x4a' | '\x4b' | '\x4c' | '\x4d' | '\x4e' | '\x4f' | '\x50' | 
  '\x51' | '\x52' | '\x53' | '\x54' | '\x55' | '\x56' | '\x57' | '\x58' | 
  '\x59' | '\x5a' ;
r__5 : 
  '\x30' | '\x31' | '\x32' | '\x33' | '\x34' | '\x35' | '\x36' | '\x37' | 
  '\x38' | '\x39' ;
r__6 : 
  '\x41' | '\x42' | '\x43' | '\x44' | '\x45' | '\x46' | '\x47' | '\x48' | 
  '\x49' | '\x4a' | '\x4b' | '\x4c' | '\x4d' | '\x4e' | '\x4f' | '\x50' | 
  '\x51' | '\x52' | '\x53' | '\x54' | '\x55' | '\x56' | '\x57' | '\x58' | 
  '\x59' | '\x5a' ;
r__7 : 
  '\x21' | '\x22' | '\x23' | '\x24' | '\x25' | '\x26' | '\x27' | '\x28' | 
  '\x29' | '\x2a' | '\x2b' | '\x2c' | '\x2d' | '\x2e' | '\x2f' | '\x30' | 
  '\x31' | '\x32' | '\x33' | '\x34' | '\x35' | '\x36' | '\x37' | '\x38' | 
  '\x39' | '\x3a' | '\x3b' | '\x3c' | '\x3d' | '\x3e' | '\x3f' | '\x40' | 
  '\x41' | '\x42' | '\x43' | '\x44' | '\x45' | '\x46' | '\x47' | '\x48' | 
  '\x49' | '\x4a' | '\x4b' | '\x4c' | '\x4d' | '\x4e' | '\x4f' | '\x50' | 
  '\x51' | '\x52' | '\x53' | '\x54' | '\x55' | '\x56' | '\x57' | '\x58' | 
  '\x59' | '\x5a' | '\x5b' | '\x5c' | '\x5d' | '\x5e' | '\x5f' | '\x60' | 
  '\x61' | '\x62' | '\x63' | '\x64' | '\x65' | '\x66' | '\x67' | '\x68' | 
  '\x69' | '\x6a' | '\x6b' | '\x6c' | '\x6d' | '\x6e' | '\x6f' | '\x70' | 
  '\x71' | '\x72' | '\x73' | '\x74' | '\x75' | '\x76' | '\x77' | '\x78' | 
  '\x79' | '\x7a' | '\x7b' | '\x7c' | '\x7d' | '\x7e' ;

/* String Expansions */
s__0 : 
 'H' 'T' 'T' 'P' ;
s__1 : 
 'G' 'E' 'T' ;
s__2 : 
 'H' 'E' 'A' 'D' ;
s__3 : 
 'P' 'O' 'S' 'T' ;
s__4 : 
 'P' 'U' 'T' ;
s__5 : 
 'D' 'E' 'L' 'E' 'T' 'E' ;
s__6 : 
 'C' 'O' 'N' 'N' 'E' 'C' 'T' ;
s__7 : 
 'O' 'P' 'T' 'I' 'O' 'N' 'S' ;
s__8 : 
 'T' 'R' 'A' 'C' 'E' ;



Please provide a simplified grammar that demonstrates the problem.

Basically, the way you debug and fix this, is to use bison's -v option to get a .output file showing the generated PDA state machine and any conflicts.
When you do this, you see 4 separate states that have shift reduce conflicts.  The first of these is
State 187  
   
    6 headerField: fieldName ':' OWS . fieldValue OWS CRLF
  122 OWS: OWS . WS
    
    ' '   shift, and go to state 38
    '\t'  shift, and go to state 477

    ' '       [reduce using rule 7 (fieldValue)]
    '\t'      [reduce using rule 7 (fieldValue)]
    $default  reduce using rule 7 (fieldValue)
   
    fieldValue  go to state 724
    SP          go to state 725
    HTAB        go to state 726
    WS          go to state 727

This is basically telling you that after seeing some OWS (zero or more whitespace characters), and seeing whitespace as the lookahead, it does not know whether to reduce an 'empty' fieldValue or continue accumulating whitespace.  The default resolution (continue skipping whitespace, do NOT assume an empty field value) is ok for parsing this, but if you need to get rid of the conflict, you need to rewrite the grammar to not have this ambiguity.  The obvious way is to disallow an empty fieldValue and instead allow that as a variant headerField:
headerField : fieldName ':' OWS fieldValue OWS CRLF
            | fieldName ':' OWS CRLF ;

fieldValue : fieldValueSS | fieldValue fieldValueSS ;

The other 3 cases can be examined similarly.
